# Combo box change value event

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I have product that supports multiple databases. During installation I would like to have a combo box that contains all databases it supports. Also there is a text box where user can enter connection string. I would like to have connection string template for each supported database and when combo box is changes, I would like to show in text box connection string template related to selected database.

Comment: This is not possible with the Windows Installer UI. There's simply no combobox_changed event...

Answer (score 0):

As Yan said this is not possible to do on one screen. However you could have the dropdown on it's own page and then after clicking next work out what the user selected by testing the property which is set and populate the textbox with the correct template.